# Why isn't pull-right working for my Bootstrap navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

See the Information section of the navbar [here](http://www.collegeanswerz.com/university-of-pittsburgh/academics/professors/do-professors-explain-things-clearly-are-professors-interesting). I'm trying to get it to float right. I used `.pull-right` like the Bootstrap docs [say](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navbar), but it isn't working.

I also tried messing around with Inspect Element and applying `float: right !important;` directly to the `li`, which didn't work, and then to the `a`, which also didn't work.

This is my code:

```
<div class="navbar"">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li id="academics" class="dropdown main_college_nav_item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Academics <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li id="professors"><a>Professors</a></li>
                    <li id="classes"><a>Classes</a></li>
                    <li id="difficulty"><a>Difficulty</a></li>
                    <li id="major"><a>Majors</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li id="living_environment" class="dropdown main_college_nav_item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Living Environment <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li id="campus"><a>Campus</a></li>
                  <li id="food"><a>Food</a></li>
                  <li id="housing"><a>Housing</a></li>
                  <li id="weather"><a>Weather</a></li>
                  <li id="safety"><a>Safety</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li id="social_life" class="dropdown main_college_nav_item"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Social Life <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li id="kids"><a>Kids/Atmosphere</a></li>
                  <li id="parties"><a>Parties</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li id="information" class="main_college_nav_item"><a class="pull-right">Information <i class="icon-resize-vertical"> </i></a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you give a bootply or jsfiddle for it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below HTML instead of your HTML.

I have created Separate `ul` for the Information tab and floated to right.

Update: **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/28vun/)**

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li id="academics" class="dropdown main_college_nav_item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Academics <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li id="professors" class="active"><a>Professors</a></li>
                    <li id="classes"><a>Classes</a></li>
                    <li id="difficulty"><a>Difficulty</a></li>
                    <li id="major"><a>Majors</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li id="living_environment" class="dropdown main_college_nav_item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Living Environment <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li id="campus"><a>Campus</a></li>
                  <li id="food"><a>Food</a></li>
                  <li id="housing"><a>Housing</a></li>
                  <li id="weather"><a>Weather</a></li>
                  <li id="safety"><a>Safety</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li id="social_life" class="dropdown main_college_nav_item"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Social Life <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li id="kids"><a>Kids/Atmosphere</a></li>
                  <li id="parties"><a>Parties</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>

        </ul>



<ul class="nav pull-right">

            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li id="information" class="main_college_nav_item"><a>Information <i class="icon-resize-vertical"> </i></a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @SurjithSM : play with browser width and it screws up....this is not bootstrap feature...its supposed to be responsive

Comment: @NoobEditor I didn't even added resposnive.css and supporting HTML :-) The site given by OP is also not responsive.